# stored procedure, how to handle errorcode: 1062

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am trying to make a stored procedure handler for duplicate username entries. 

the procedure manages to create it self, but when i enter inn the information into the tables i only get the standard error from mysql. How do i sort this out?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Testproc2$$

create procedure testproc2(filename VARCHAR (40), descriptionn VARCHAR(40),
username VARCHAR(40), firstname VARCHAR(40), lastnameVARCHAR(40), classcode INT(10))

begin
declare exit handler for 1062
    select concat('Feil: username',username,'already exist');
    start transaction;

   insert into bilde 
    values (NULL, filnavn, beskrivelse);

    insert into student 
    values (username, firstname, lastname, classcode, LAST_INSERT_ID());
    commit;

  SELECT CONCAT('Inserted student ',username,' ',firstname' ',lastname' ',classcode' ', LAST_INSERT_ID());
  END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error, i called for testproc1 instead of testproc2.